# HTML/CSS Dropdown menu issue (Dropdown list appearing on the same line)

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

I'm having an issue with creating dropdown lists. What is supposed to happen when you hover over the 'Stages' anchor is that the list is supposed to appear directly below it. But for some reason, it is appearing to the left of the bar, on the same line.

This is driving me nuts. Can somebody help me with this issue?

```
<body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>About</a></li>
                    <li><a>Stages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Stage #1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stage #2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stage #3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(196,196,196);
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid rgb(0, 199, 255);
}

div#navigation {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 199, 255);
}

div#navigation > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative
}

div#navigation ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

div#navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(135, 206, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
}

div#navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

div#navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

div#navigation ul ul li {
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(196,196,196);
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid rgb(0, 199, 255);
}

div#navigation {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 199, 255);
}

div#navigation > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
}

div#navigation > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

div#navigation ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    position: realtive;
}

div#navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(135, 206, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
}

div#navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;


}

div#navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
}

div#navigation ul ul li {
    display: block; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5wvgdubk/

I moved the `float` from the `a` to the `li` and added `position: relative` so that the inner `ul` is placed correctly. I also removed the padding from the inner `ul`.

Comment: Works perfectly! If I could upvote and mark more than one answer correct, I would do so, but it's a shame that I can't.

Thank you for your time, though. I greatly appreciate it. I hope you will accept my words. :)

TO EVERYONE READING THIS COMMENT: THIS SOLUTION ALSO WORKS!

Comment: @Chosen1 No problem :) The other solution works too, it's just that I don't like the hardcoded `top: 47px` very much. It breaks if the height of your links ever changes.

Comment: On second thought, I've given the 'correct' answer to you. Your solution is more flexible, so you've pipped the post on this one. Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin` and control your droplist. Like this:

```
div#navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. It's just a shame that I'm not allowed to up vote more than one answer. Thank you for investing your time in this. I appreciate it. NOTE TO ALL: THIS IS A VALID SOLUTION.

Comment: @Chosen1 it's ok. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

add a top:50px; to drop it down and add a left attribute, preferably in percent, although in testing this doesn;t work perfectly, you may have to add `media queries`.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g46h7xtc/1/)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid rgb(0, 199, 255);
}
div#navigation {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 199, 255);
}
div#navigation > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative
}
div#navigation ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}
div#navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(135, 206, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 250, 250);
}
div#navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
div#navigation ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left:10px;
    top:75px;
    left:32%;
}
div#navigation ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a>About</a></li>
                <li><a>Stages</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Stage #1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stage #2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stage #3</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Once again, another great valid solution! I wish I could also upvote, but I don't have 15 rep points. :( I truly appreciate your time and investment into this, Rachel. I hope my words are enough show you my gratitude :)

NOTE: THIS IS ANOTHER VALID SOLUTION.

Comment: @Chosen1 your words are appreciated :) and we all started out with no rep. maybe when you have more you'll come back to this q and vote up all the good answers ;)

Comment: Will do. I've favourited this page on my browser anyway, so I'll make sure to come back and give you all an upvote. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding margin and padding 0 to div#navigation ul ul and a top px aligns the submenu underneath:

```
div#navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/co9npmnh/

Comment: Perfect! I spent hours trying to figure this out and you have sorted it out with just three attributes. Thanks for your help!