# Dropdown items on same line + hover effect goes to far to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that I want to be able to use dropdown menus but the w3schools one that I found display items on same line + the hover background color change is too wide. could someone have a look at it and tell me what goes wrong?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/e7zLx39u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have `.nav-item-holder a {display: inline}`, where actually you want this to by `display: block`;
2. I would also add `.nav-item-holder .dropdown-content a { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }` to make sure you don't have any jumps of the items when you hover them.

Here is a working version of your code, fix (with my 2 suggestion)

```css
.nav-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 color:#151618;
 background-color:#151618;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom:4px solid #0bb1ff;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1;
 margin-top:0 auto;
}

.nav-logo {
 width:45px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 top:5%;
} 

.nav-item {
 float:left;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #151618;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 color:#0bb1ff;
 text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
 color:#fff;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#0bb1ff;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #151618;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #151618;
    border:3px solid #0bb1ff;
    text-align: center;
    width:180px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #0bb1ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #0bb1ff; color:#fff; width:100%;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    clear:both;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #0bb1ff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 color:#fff;
}

.nav-item-holder {
 z-index:3;
 color:#151618;
 font:14px verdana;
 line-height:50px;
 left:50px;
 position:absolute;
}

.nav-item-holder a {
 display: block;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 color:#0bb1ff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item-holder a:hover {
 position:relative;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:#0bb1ff;
 height:100%;
}
.nav-item-holder .dropdown-content a {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.active {
 position:relative;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:#0bb1ff;
 height:100%;
}

.user-image {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 position:absolute;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
 -moz-border-radius: 99em;
 border-radius: 99em;
 border: 2px solid #0bb1ff;
 top:8px;
 right:30px;
}

.nav-user {
 line-height: 50px;
 color:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
}

.nav-user span {
 display:inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right:70px;
}

.nav-user-drop {
 position:absolute;
 display:none;

}

.nav-user:hover .nav-user-drop {
 display:block;
}

.user-drop {
 padding:5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:#151618;
 color:#0bb1ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-content">
    <a class="nav-logo" href="/"><img src="/assets/images/templates/volcan.png" class="nav-logo"/></a>

    <div class="nav-item-holder">
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="" >Forum</a></div>
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="" >Article</a></div>
     
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn">Discover</div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Top</a>
          <a href="#">Recent</a>
          <a href="#">Verified</a>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>


    <form>
      <!--Gone add search bar-->
    </form>


 
    </div>
    <div class="nav-user-drop">
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Profile</a>
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Inbox</a>
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Settings</a>
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Sign Out</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sub items are set to inline-block. If you comment out the following line, that should sort that out, and they'll all stack beneath each other.

```
.nav-item-holder a {
    /* display: inline-block; */
}
```

Not sure if that covers everything; let me know and I'll extend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-wrapper {
 position: fixed;
 color:#151618;
 background-color:#151618;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom:4px solid #0bb1ff;
 height:50px;
 z-index:1;
 margin-top:0 auto;
}

.nav-logo {
 width:45px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 top:5%;
} 

.nav-item {
 float:left;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #151618;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 color:#0bb1ff;
 text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
 color:#fff;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#0bb1ff;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #151618;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #151618;
    border:3px solid #0bb1ff;
    text-align: center;
    width:180px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.nav-item-holder .dropdown-content a {
    color: #0bb1ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block !important;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #0bb1ff; color:#fff; width:100%;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
    clear:both;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #0bb1ff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 color:#fff;
}

.nav-item-holder {
 z-index:3;
 color:#151618;
 font:14px verdana;
 line-height:50px;
 left:50px;
 position:absolute;
}

.nav-item-holder a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;
 color:#0bb1ff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item-holder a:hover {
 position:relative;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:#0bb1ff;
 height:100%;
}

.active {
 position:relative;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color:#0bb1ff;
 height:100%;
}

.user-image {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 position:absolute;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-border-radius: 99em;
 -moz-border-radius: 99em;
 border-radius: 99em;
 border: 2px solid #0bb1ff;
 top:8px;
 right:30px;
}

.nav-user {
 line-height: 50px;
 color:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
}

.nav-user span {
 display:inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right:70px;
}

.nav-user-drop {
 position:absolute;
 display:none;

}

.nav-user:hover .nav-user-drop {
 display:block;
}

.user-drop {
 padding:5px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color:#151618;
 color:#0bb1ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-content">
    <a class="nav-logo" href="/"><img src="/assets/images/templates/volcan.png" class="nav-logo"/></a>

    <div class="nav-item-holder">
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="" >Forum</a></div>
      <div class="nav-item"><a href="" >Article</a></div>
     
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn">Discover</div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Top</a>
          <a href="#">Recent</a>
          <a href="#">Verified</a>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>


    <form>
      <!--Gone add search bar-->
    </form>


 
    </div>
    <div class="nav-user-drop">
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Profile</a>
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Inbox</a>
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Settings</a>
      <a href="" class="user-drop">Sign Out</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width from hover state and ad it to the class also subtract padding you gave her the sample

```
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #0bb1ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #0bb1ff; color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't know if this is totally a duplicate, so just putting the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171431/html-css-dropdown-menu-issue-dropdown-list-appearing-on-the-same-line)

Next, I changed the width of the box from 180px to 80px, and the problem was solved. But, generically, you might want to change `.nav-holder-item {display : inline; }` to `{ display: block; }` in the css.

Hope this helps.